# Closing js files in Visual Studio in TACO project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, taco

On current week I faced with following issue. I load any Cordova App project in Visual Studio 2015. Open any js file in the editor. And then click the Save button (or press Ctrl+S). After that  the tab with js file is closed. And this file is removed from the Solution Explorer. This behavior is reproduced even on empty Blank Apache Cordova Application template.

Before this week all works properly. It may be related with recent Windows updates. Any case I cannot work with my project.


My environment:

- Windows 10,
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update
  3
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova   Update 10